# Is sub-domain is considered part from the primany domain by Google?

Tags: seo, subdomain

Sub-domain such as http://blog.example.com is considered a part from http://example.com or it is concerned as different domain by Google?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about seo, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Google consider it to be part of the same domain.  For example, blog.example.com is 'linked' to example.com.  A good example is Wikipedia.  Do a quick Google search for a well known entity or topic (i.e. 'England').  The second result is `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England` - a subdomain of Wikipedia.

Long story short: using a subdomain shouldn't affect your search ranking.

Comment: Oops, I wanted to have this blog to supplement my website and provide quality content so that my SEO gets a boost.

Comment: It should interact with Google in the same way as if your blog was `example.com/blog/`